# Using server name in pattern with multiple http elements Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring Security 3.1 supports multiple http elements.

I would like to have the security for our mobile site to basically always require a login whereas the "normal" website will have a lot more public pages.

I was thinking of using the multiple http elements feature of Spring Security for this, but I can't find anything about using variables such as server name (e.g. m.site.com) in the pattern field.

Can I use request variables in the http pattern field. If so, how?

Here's some of the code i tried:

```
    <http security="none" pattern="/assets/**"/>
<!-- 
<http use-expressions="true" request-matcher-ref="mobileHttpConfigSelector" entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" >

    <intercept-url pattern="/*/*/login.html"  access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*/*/registration/**"  access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <anonymous enabled="true" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="${msa.security.key}" use-secure-cookie="true"/>
    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myUserPassFilter"/>
    <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="myLogoutFilter"/>
    <custom-filter ref="countrySelectFilter" before="FIRST" />
    <custom-filter ref="userAgentFilter" before="LAST" />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/" session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas">
    </session-management>
</http>
-->
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" >

    <intercept-url pattern="/*/*/account/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="permitAll" />

    <anonymous enabled="true" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="${msa.security.key}" use-secure-cookie="true"/>

    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myUserPassFilter"/>
    <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="myLogoutFilter"/>
    <custom-filter ref="countrySelectFilter" before="FIRST" />
    <custom-filter ref="userAgentFilter" before="LAST" />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/" session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas">
        <!-- <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>-->
    </session-management>
</http>
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<beans:bean id="mobileHttpConfigSelector" class="nl.msw.compraventa.interceptor.security.MobileHttpConfigSelector"/>
```

The http section with mobileHttpConfigSelector has been commented out because if I activate I get No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository] is defined.

Kind regards,
Marc

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `request-matcher-ref` attribute instead of `pattern` to inject a `RequestMatcher` instance which can make use of any data in the `HttpRequest`. Using `pattern` is just a special case where the [`AntPathRequestMatcher`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher.html) is used to select the filter chain.

See the [namespace appendix](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-http) for more information on available attributes.

Comment: Cool. I'm just wondering if you can use this to select the appropriate http configuration and then let spring security use its standard intercept-url from there. Looks like: yes.

Comment: Turns out: No. I tried it and I can't use two http definitions with a RequestMatcher that switches between the two. I'm getting an error thrown that suggest I need to use a pattern to distinguish between the two. Problem is: the pattern is identical. It is the server name that differs. Any ideas?

Comment: Having the just first alternative http configuration with request-matcher-ref also throws up an error: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository] is defined

Comment: I'd suggest you post the code, 'cos it's not obvious from your comments what you've done or what the error is. In a filter chain all the client-supplied information have access to is the request. So when you say "server name" you should be asking yourself what that means in terms of the request. I don't really know from your description, but I'd guess that it is available from the `requestURI` property or from the host header which the HTTP client should send.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my original post with the code. The issue is not that I can't create a RequestMatcher. The issue is how I can have a different http configuration based on the value of some request properties, in this case: the server name.

Comment: You need to get the server name from the request in the RequestMatchers, most likely from the [host header](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName()) (see my previous comment).